# Scala match int on enumeration

Tags: scala, enums, pattern-matching

```
val size: Int = o.getSize

size match
{
    case MyObject.Size.small.id => println("Small")
    case MyObject.Size.medium.id => println("Medium")
    case _ => throw ne UnknownSizeException
}
```

Won't compile, I get strange errors in my IDE, but this is because I'm using gradle and a lot of legacy Java-Code I've to gradually update.

I'm still not sure, why this doesn't work. Small has the id of 1, Medium of 2.

Now if I match like this:

```
  case s: MyObject.Size.small.id => println("Small")
```

> symbol id cannot be resolved.

Why is that?

If I manually add 1 and 2 everything works like a charm.

**edit**

I think one problem would be that the .id starts with zero, while my size starts with 1 (makes sense here, as it's an actual size)

But this alone can't be the problem, can it? Because I'd match to _ anyway.

But how could I overcome that?

```
case MyObject.Size.small.id + 1 => println("Won't work!")
```

**edit: My actual solution, thanks to Sascha Kolberg**

```
MyObject.Size(size+1) match
{
    case MyObject.Size.SMALL => ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: What type is MyObject.Size.small.id?  The reason for the second problem (symbol id) is that you've said that the type of s is MyObject.Size.small.id, which is not a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `Enumeration` you cannot match on `Enumeration.Value.id` because it is a `def`and for pattern matching you need stable identifiers, which basically means `val`.

You match on the enumeration values, so try this:

```
MyObject.Size(size) match
{
  case MyObject.Size.small => println("Small")
  case MyObject.Size.medium => println("Medium")
  case _ => throw new UnknownSizeException
}
```